# How can you tell if a given point is inside a STereoLithography (.stl) file object c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to determine of a point is inside a polyhedron imported from a STereoLithography (.stl) file. I'm wondering if there is a C++ solution/library already in existence that solves this problem.

I'm looking to avoid shelling to the [Matlab solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume-)

Comment: "Inside an stl object"? You mean you have say, a `std::vector` that contains points, forming a polyhedron, and you want to tell if a point is inside or outside the polyhedron? There is no function for doing that in standard C++, but I'm sure there are geometry packages available that does such things. Or one could write a small piece of code to determine such a thing...

Comment: an stl file would contain points and their normal vectors yes.

Comment: with the property that the normals should point from the inside of the body to the outside (computed normal is outwards)

Comment: Could you give an example of the data?

Comment: One could use any .stl object found on thingiverse: e.g. http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:506567

Comment: Inside the object being within its volume

Comment: First misunderstanding cleaned up: stl is not standard template library but instead [STereoLithography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29).

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is anything in [boost::geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) that can help you?

Comment: I wonder if the CGAL library  https://www.cgal.org/ is worth looking at

Comment: You could also try compiling the Matlab `inpolyhedron` code to C or C++ using [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/)/[`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html). This [blog post from The MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/) goes through some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The theory of the problem is somewhat simple, when you go from a point to the outside you will have to pass an odd number of facings (triangles).

Some pseudo code

```
Vector3d toOutside { point, pointOutside }; // !!! how do we know a point is outside ?!?
for_each(triangleList, [&count, =toOutside](Triangle& triangle) { 
    if (Intersect(triangle, toOutside) // some fussiness with edges and triangle points.
        ++count;
}

if (count %2 == 1) 
    isInside = true;
else
    isOutside = false;
```

Finding a point outside the polyhedron, find the highest x,y,z and add 1.0 to them.

Pseudo prof [ToDo:link to article with more rigid prof]
Simple case a box, if we are inside a box, there will be one intersection with a side if we follow the toOutside vector.
If we are inside a polyhedron, then if we pass through a triangle we are outside, if we then pass through 2 triangles more (in and out) we can still tell we were inside. If we in fact were outside the polyhedron we will pass through and even number of triangles (or zero) when following the toOutside vector.

A C++ implementation at [geometrictools](http://www.geometrictools.com/GTEngine/Include/GteContPointInPolyhedron3.h) look under mathematics->containment->point-in-polyhedron->3D for both .h and .inl files.

There might be some more optimized tests that uses the normal vector for the outside.
Also if you have multiple objects you need to test against, consider making a bounding box for each to use for culling, as the vector tests can be expensive.